# How to set path in bitbake append file?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am updating a device tree in Beagle Bone Black to enable i2c configuration. I have created a new layer meta-test. In meta-test there is a recipes-kernel where I have a **leds.cfg** and **am335x-boneblack.dts** file with **linux-yocto_%.bbappend** file. The bbappend file looks like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"

SRC_URI += "\
file://am335x-boneblack.dts \
file://leds.cfg \
"
```

After building the kernel with **bitbake** both the files are transferred to "build/tmp/work/beaglebone_yocto-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-yocto/4.18.25+git**" directory

But I want the dts file to get transfer to another directory "build/tmp/work-shared/beaglebone-yocto/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts
"

How do I achieve this within the bbappend file?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? [kernel-devicetree.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/classes/kernel-devicetree.bbclass) should take care of it without doing it manually I suppose. Otherwise you can maybe add something like `do_compile_prepend(){ cp ${WORKDIR}/am335x-boneblack.dts ${S}/arch/${ARCH}/boot/dts/ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it adding this line:

```
do_configure_append() {
    cp ${WORKDIR}/am335x-boneblack.dts ${S}/arch/arm/boot/dts/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending the files to `SRC_URI` in the linux-yocto recipe you're adding the files to the linux-yocto workdir not to the actual kernel-source workdir. You have 2 options in order to make those files available from the kernel-source folder:

- **Move/C&P the files.** Inside the linux-yocto workdir, the folder *linux-beaglebone_yocto-standard-build/sources* is a symlink to *build/tmp/work-shared/beaglebone_yocto/kernel-source*. Hence, you can copy&paste/move the files to that folder using cp/mv in your bbappend.
- **Create a patch.** You can add those files in the form of a patch to the kernel source instead and, thus, just include the patch in your bbappend (appending it to `SRC_URI`, as usual).

These are, IMO, the best options. However, you could just keep your files in a folder structure like *linux-beaglebone-yocto-standard-build/sources/arch/arm/boot/dts/yourfile.dtb* (inside the directory of the recipe) and then add them to `SRC_URI` (they will be automatically added to that path).